# Looking for some guidance on using Mongoose with express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I need a bit of help understanding how to use mongoose with express. I found a tutorial that has helped me create an API that returns records from a MongoDB using an MVC type of pattern but rather than return to my router it writes the results to the response, because it's an API...

Here is the high level setup

**Form.Model** - Contains the Schema of my Form object

**Form.Controller** - Contains the code to return records from the database

**Form.Router** - this is my router that returns the results to the response object.

Here is an example route that I am struggling with, I want to convert this to something that instead of writing to the res I want to return the results and then use them in my Router.

```
// Retrieve all Forms from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    const email = req.query.solcon;
    var condition = email ? { email: { $regex: new RegExp(email), $options: "i" } } : {};
  
    Form.find(condition)
      .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving Forms."
        });
      });
  };
```

Code from my router (probably not correct) Basically I want to call the Form router, return the forms and then send them to my index ejs page.

```
router.get('/',function(req, res, next) {    
    let formList =forms.findAll(req.oidc.user.email);            
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', user: req.oidc.user.email, forms : formList });
});
```

I am far from an expert or even proficient at using promises, async await... so having a hard time altering this code to work correctly.

Could someone please help me convert this find all function to something that I could use in my Form.Router to send the results to the index page.

Answer (score 0):

Your `findAll` doesn't seem to be doing that much to warrant its own method so one option could be to just move the logic into the router callback like so:

```js
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) { //< Mark callback as async
   try{
      const email = req.query.solcon;
      const condition = email ? { email: { $regex: new RegExp(email), $options: "i" } } : {};
    
      const formList = await Form.find(condition); //< Now you can await the results            
      res.render('index', { 
         title: 'Express', 
         user: req.oidc.user.email, 
         forms: formList 
      });
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.render('index', { 
         title: 'Express', 
         message: 'Error on server'
      });
   }   
});
```

Alternatively you could use `findAll` as the callback like so:

```js
exports.findAll = async (req, res) => { //< Mark as async
   try{
      const email = req.query.solcon;
      const condition = email ? { email: { $regex: new RegExp(email), $options: "i" } } : {};
    
      const formList = await Form.find(condition); //< Now you can await the results            
      return res.render('index', { 
         title: 'Express', 
         user: req.oidc.user.email, 
         forms: formList 
      });
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.render('index', { 
         title: 'Express', 
         message: 'Error on server'
      });
   }   
};
```

Then use that in your `router` like so:

```js
router.get('/', forms.findAll);
```